# Using C11's _Generic to emulate default value of argument

Tags: c, c11

I have two functions with following signatures:

```
Memory memInitDebug (Size size, Size base);
```

and

```
Memory memInitRelease (Size size);
```

*(`Size` is a typedef for `size_t`)*

In implementation, `memInitRelease` simply calls `memInitDebug` with the value of `base` as 0.

Is there any way to use `_Generic` to emulate default value of arguments so that I can have a single function/macro `memInit` that selects the appropriate function based on the number of arguments?

(Currently, I am using Clang's `overloadable` attribute to achieve this but I'd rather not use compiler extensions).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please try to avoid making up your own type-aliases for standard types (like `size_t`). No one else but you will know about such aliases unless explicitly told about it, and if you forget then reading the code will make no sense.